# Python, why does this function go into an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def new_if (pred,then_clause,else_clause):

    if pred:
        then_clause
    else:
        else_clause

def p(x):
    new_if(x>5,print(x),p(2*x))

p(1)
```

I think the function should stop once x reaches 8 and 8 is printed out.

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: `x>5`...What are you trying to pass?

Comment: Why you are passing print function in argument ?

Comment: as i use python tutor i find out 1,2,4,8 and the following is printed out..infinite loop..

Comment: `p(2*x)` is evaluated outside the new_if function I think

Comment: if the input is larger than 5 then goes to then_clause, else goes to else_clause

Comment: @SunWeiran no it doesn't, everything is computed before entering the `new_if` function

Comment: OH thanks everyone! now i understand why does this happen! thank you guys!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just doing this in `p`? If not, you are making things far more complicated for yourself than you need to...

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Every time you call `p` it executes the code inside that method, which in your case calls `new_if` with some arguments. However you are evaluating those arguments immediately, which means before entering `new_if` your code is executing `print(x)` and `p(2*x)`. This causes `p` to get called again, repeating the process.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some general confusion in how you think your code is evaluated: in particular, what you think as predicates and clauses really are not. The arguments are evaluated *before* the call to `new_if` is made. Hence, you get a infinite recursive call to `p`, by evaluating `p(2*x)` almost as soon as you call `p`.

You could achieve what you want by passing functions, which you then evaluate within your `new_if` function. This can be done with lambda functions, like so:

```
def new_if (pred,then_clause,else_clause):
    if pred():
        then_clause()
    else:
        else_clause()

def p(x):
    new_if(lambda: x>5, lambda: print(x), lambda: p(2*x))

p(1)
```

In this case, `pred`, `then_clause`, `else_clause` are callables which you need to call (`()`) for them to be executed.