# paddles wont move in pong game and there's no visible error codes being thrown, am i missing something?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong

I'm able to run the program and the screen pops up with the paddles and the ball, the paddles just wont go up and down, but i was able to get them to move previously before i started simplifying my code and i just cant seem to find where i made a mistake or if im missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. i attached my main.py file and my paddle.py file below. And thank you again for any help

> main.py file

```
from turtle import Screen
from paddle import Paddle
from ball import Ball
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("It's Pong")
screen.tracer(0)

r_paddle = Paddle((350, 0))
l_paddle = Paddle((-350, 0))
ball = Ball()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_up(), "Up")
screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_down(), "Down")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_up(), "w")
screen.onkey(l_paddle.go_down(), "s")


game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

> paddle.py file

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.color('white')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def go_up(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() + 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)

    def go_down(self):
        new_y = self.ycor() - 20
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
```

Comment: `screen.onkey(r_paddle.go_up(), "Up")` is calling the method *once*, *right now*, and passing its return value (which is None) as the action to be performed when the key is pressed.  You want to pass the method itself, to be called later - in other words, get rid of the `()`.

Comment: @jasonharper that worked! you're a genius, I cant believe I didn't even see that. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onkeypress() function in turtle module problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983266/onkeypress-function-in-turtle-module-problem)