# Why is onclick() function calling the function inside instantly?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

In this code:

```
button = Turtle()
button2 = Turtle()
button.hideturtle(), button2.hideturtle()

button2.color("#f73487")
button2.hideturtle()
button2.shape("square")
button2.fillcolor('#f73487')
button2.shapesize(4)
button2.penup()
button2.goto(-300, 230)
button2.write("No", align='center', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
button2.setx(-300), button2.sety(182)
button2.onclick(draw_onclick2())
button2.showturtle()

button.color("#f73487")
button.hideturtle()
button.shape("square")
button.fillcolor('#f73487')
button.shapesize(4)
button.penup()
button.goto(300, 230)
button.write("Yes", align='center', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
button.setx(300), button.sety(182)
button.onclick(draw_onclick())
button.showturtle()
```

the function `button2.onclick()` that contains `draw_onclick2` just calls the function instantly without me clicking and I can't figure out why.

When I first tried it with the `button` it worked but now if I do it it just instantly calls the function.

Comment: `button.onclick(draw_onclick())` means "**call `draw_onclick` now**, and pass **the result** to `button.onclick`". You need to pass **the function itself**, so that Turtle can call it later when the button is clicked. "The function itself" is just spelled like `draw_onclick`; the `()` are **not part of the name**. Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: It cannot be instantly, superluminal communication is physically impossible.

Comment: Dupes that are more specific to Python turtle: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666432/paddles-wont-move-in-pong-game-and-theres-no-visible-error-codes-being-thrown), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983266/onkeypress-function-in-turtle-module-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button2.onclick(draw_onclick2())
                             ^^
```

This is actually an immediate *call* to the `draw_onclick2` function, and the return value from it is then passed to `onclick`.

What you need to do instead is pass the actual *function*, with something like:

```
button2.onclick(draw_onclick2)
```

---

You can see the effect in the following transcript:

```py
>>> def fn():
...     return 7
...

>>> print(fn)
<function fn at 0x7f8e36456f70>

>>> print(fn())
7
```

You can see that `fn` is the function, but `fn()` *calls* the function giving its return value.